# jQuery doesn't hide div on click

Tags: jquery, html, click, hide

I've got a HTML code:

```
<div class="FormContainer" id="FirstFormContainer">
  <form>
    <span> Wprowadź liczbę podmiotów</span></br>
    <input id="NumberOfSubjects" /></br>
    <span> Wprowadź liczbę czynników </span></br>
    <input id="NumberOfFactors"/></br>
    <input type="submit" id="FirstSubmit" value="Dalej"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {



$( "#FirstSubmit" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    $("#FirstFormContainer").css("display", "none");
  }); }
```

The problem is that the code show an alert on click but doesn't hide the #FirstFormContainer. On the other hand if I paste the code: $("#FirstFormContainer").css("display", "none"); into the browser it does work. Any ideas? :) Thanks!

Comment: Its working fine and hiding the form for me, did you check the console for errors?

Comment: I did - no errors :/ I'm not sure but I noticed that the page is refreshed after clicking on button. Maybe that is the problem why the div is not hiding. I mean it is hiding but the the page is refreshed and the div is shown again. Is it possibly that the button refresh the page:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include jquery in the head before the content, and the script tag containing your code just before the ending body tag.

Remove `type="submit"` from the input and add `type="button"` . Your form is getting submitted automatically and refreshing your page.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="FormContainer" id="FirstFormContainer">
    <form>
      <span> Wprowadź liczbę podmiotów</span><br>
      <input id="NumberOfSubjects" /><br>
      <span> Wprowadź liczbę czynników </span><br>
      <input id="NumberOfFactors" /><br>
      <input type="button" id="FirstSubmit" value="Dalej" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    $("#FirstSubmit").click(function() {
      alert("Handler for .click() called.");
      $("#FirstFormContainer").css("display", "none");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It works! The problem was type="submit". Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action to keep your page from refreshing. When you submit a form, it will refresh the page unless you tell it not to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#FirstSubmit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    $("#FirstFormContainer").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FormContainer" id="FirstFormContainer">
  <form>
    <span> Wprowadź liczbę podmiotów</span></br>
    <input id="NumberOfSubjects" /></br>
    <span> Wprowadź liczbę czynników </span></br>
    <input id="NumberOfFactors" /></br>
    <input type="submit" id="FirstSubmit" value="Dalej" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mentioned it in the question - I imported the jQuery in <head> : <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>